# How to know if a website is enabled/disabled the directory browsing using javascript

Tags: javascript, directory, directory-browsing

I want to know a random website is enabled/disabled the directory browsing like this ([Link](https://seositecheckup.com/tools/directory-browsing-test)). Is there any way to know by using javascript or possible to know via headers?

Comment: Do you mean browser JavaScript? In that case CORS could block your requests.

Answer (score 0):

Tools that check for enabled directory listing (like the one you shared) are looking for common patterns such as `Index of /some/path` present in the file (example for Apache).

What you could do is:

- Fetch from a link using `fetch`, `axios` or `similar`
- Identify patterns for different HTTP servers (apache2, nginx, lighthttpd)
- Look for this patterns in the fetched content